# How to render based on AJAX result in react js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, fetch-api, react-functional-component

Just want to render movie cards based on results that come from ajax call.

Currently, the movie cards components are rendered based on that hard code array named list. I just want to make it dynamic and replace it with my ajax data.

```
const getlist = async () => {
  const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/customize');
  const data = await response.json();
  getlist();
};

export default function Index() {

  const list = ['dexter', 'bb', 'got'];

  return (
    <>
      <main className={parentstyle.main_container}>
        <NavBar />
        <div className={style.searchbar_container}>
          <SearchBar />
        </div>
        <div className={style.card_container}>
          {test.map((element, i) => {
            return <MovieCard movieName={element} key={i} />;
          })}
        </div>
      </main>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: The easiest solution is probably to use the [SWR library](https://swr.vercel.app/), which provides a `useSWR()` hook that does this kind of simple data fetching for you. (This example is pretty much exactly what you're looking for: https://swr.vercel.app/examples/basic)

Comment: You need useState for list to store list data, then for an intial call you have to use useEffect which will call getList and set data to list

Comment: Render based on the data, and simply update the data with the ajax result when it arrives.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook to set up your component state (the *list*) and fetch data in a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook...

> The Effect Hook lets you perform side effects in function components:
>
> **Data fetching**, setting up a subscription, and manually changing the DOM in React components are all examples of side effects. Whether or not you’re used to calling these operations “side effects” (or just “effects”), you’ve likely performed them in your components before.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const getlist = async () => {
  const res = await fetch("http://localhost:3001/customize")
  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(`${res.status}: ${await res.text()}`)
  }
  return res.json()
}

const Index = () => {

  const [ list, setList ] = useState([]) // start with an empty array

  useEffect(() => {
    getList()
      .then(setList)
      .catch(console.error)
  }, []) // empty dependencies array, this runs only once

  return (
    // ...

    {list.map((element, i) => (
      <MovieCard movieName={element} key={i} />
    ))}

    // ...
  )
}

export default Index
```